# how to use the widget.place(x,y) function to pack a widget in a frame - when trying to switch between couple of frames? (tkinter python)

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I'm trying to link between the starting page of my application to different frames by using different buttons - each one will link to a different frame.

when I used the widget.pack() function to place my widgets on the screen - I was able to link between those frames successfully :

```
 from Tkinter import *


def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500+250+110")

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

b1 = Button(f1, text='Go to frame 2', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2))
b1.pack()

l1 = Label(f1, text='FRAME 1')
l1.pack()


l2 = Label(f2, text='FRAME 2')
l2.pack()


b2 = Button(f2, text='Go to frame 1', command=lambda:raise_frame(f1))
b2.pack()



raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

But, when I used the function Widget.Place(x,y) in addition to the widget.pack() function to place my widgets on the screen, trying to place the widgets at specific spots - I wasn't able to link between the different frames, and my opening page was blank - the widgets didn't appear:

```
  from Tkinter import *


def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500+250+110")

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

b1 = Button(f1, text='Go to frame 2', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2))
b1.pack()
b1.place(x=100,y=200)

l1 = Label(f1, text='FRAME 1')
l1.pack()
l1.place(x=200, y=300)


l2 = Label(f2, text='FRAME 2')
l2.pack()
l2.place(x=200, y=300)


b2 = Button(f2, text='Go to frame 3', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3))
b2.pack()
b2.place(x=100,y=200)



raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

**my question is - is there an option to use the widget.place(x,y) function in order to place widgets on the frame ? or do I have to use the widget.pack() function? ( where I can't place my widget on a specific spot)**

thank you!

Comment: A correction -  b2 = Button(f2, text='Go to frame **1** ', command=lambda:raise_frame(**f1**)) - i accidently copied it as f3.  i'd really appreciate it if you could help me :)

Comment: Add `root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... when I used the function Widget.Place(x,y) in addition to the widget.pack() function...

You can only use one or the other. The last one you use is the one that is in control. When you do `x.pack(...); x.place(...)` it is precisely the same as if you just did `x.place(...)` - the call to `pack()` has absolutely no affect.

> is there an option to use the widget.place(x,y) function in order to place widgets on the frame ?

Yes, of course, you always have the option to use `place`. In my experience it is virtually never the right solution, however. Your code is a good example of why it ends up requiring you to do a lot more work.

You start by creating a parent frame -- `f1` and `f2` -- and don't give them a size. The default size is only one pixel. You're using `grid` in the root window but you aren't giving a weight to the cell that those frames are in, so that row and column stays one pixel tall and wide.

One of the features of `place` is that it doesn't affect the size of the parent. 
When you use `place` to add a widget to the frame, the frame stays a single pixel. So, the frame is actually there, and the button is placed within the frame at the specific coordinate, but the frame is effectively invisible since it's only one pixel wide and tall.

You can see this for yourself by forcing the frames to be a specific width (eg: `f1 = Frame(root, background="red", width=300, height=300)`), or by using the proper `place`, or `grid` options to force the frames to fill the window (eg: using `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to give all extra space to row zero and column zero).